# Toggle between two ion icons

Tags: ionic-framework

I am new to ionic, trying to figure out how to accomplish the below task.

- I want to toggle between 2 ion icons  and  Any help to move in the right direction would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure! Here's an easy implementation if you're using Angular. Click to toggle between thumbs up and thumbs down.

JavaScript/Typescript

```js
showThumbsUp = true;

toggleThumb() {
    if (this.showThumbsUp) {
      this.showThumbsUp = false;
    } else {
      this.showThumbsUp = true;
    }
  }
```

HTML

```html
<ion-content>
  <ion-fab vertical="center" horizontal="center" slot="fixed" (click)="toggleThumb()">
    <ion-fab-button>
      <ion-icon *ngIf="showThumbsUp" name="thumbs-up"></ion-icon>
      <ion-icon *ngIf="!showThumbsUp" name="thumbs-down"></ion-icon>
    </ion-fab-button>
  </ion-fab>
</ion-content>
```